# Differentiating multiple SMTP listeners in Twisted program

Tags: python, email, smtp, twisted

I have an Python application that I want to listen on multiple ports for SMTP clients.  I have working smtp.SMTPFactory subclass, smtp.IMessageDelivery implementation, etc.

What I have not been able to figure out is how to tell, inside the smtp.IMessageDelivery instance, which SMTPFactory instance is active.

To be more specific, I need to be able to tell which instance (port, etc) has caused the message handler's eomReceived method to be called.  I need to handle dispatching/saving the eMail message differently depending on which address/port it came in on.

The smtp.IMessageDelivery and smtp.IMessage interfaces don't seem to have any way to trace back up the call chain to get any information about the Factory instance that are calling them.

My code is all based on https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/_downloads/emailserver.tac

Comment: In you title, is it SNMP or SMTP?

Comment: SMTP.  Darn acronyms.

Comment: Usually the port and host info are found in the ``Protocol`` object.  Therefore, your best bet to get that info would be to modify ``ConsoleSMTPFactory.buildProtocol()`` and pass in the ``addr`` argument to ``ConsoleMessage``.  Just a guess though

Comment: @notorious - doesn't work.  The addr parameter to the SMTPFactory buildProtocol method is the address of the client (sender).  I need to figure out how to tell which Listener is creating the factory.